# Is Meteor JS flexible to be full stack framework?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs, meteor

I've read some interesting articles and comparisons on JavaScript MV* frameworks and I do know *outline* of architecture of most popular ones (Ember, Backbone, Angular) However as a PHP programmer (and Symfony 2 lover) who wants to learn one of those in detail, I am concerned if [Meteor](http://meteor.com) (my first choice) is flexible enough to be considered a full stack framework so I can abandon server side (eg. PHP) entirely on **most** basic apps. Until today I thought that PHP + Angular give more possibilites (although it's more time consuming to maintain both server and client side), however I'd like your opinion on that. From what I've seen in meteor's screencast, it seems pretty awesome.

Comment: I didn't understand. You want to abandon server side completely?

Comment: Just for clarification: you don't abandon the server side. Meteor runs on the server.

Comment: @Carsten that's right. It uses nodejs. That's why I asked what he meant by "abandon server side entirely on most basic apps" :)

Comment: @thinklinux, I don't know it is possible or it is advisable, that's why I'm asking. E.g., how does meteor deal with authorization layer? Should I implement my own?

Comment: @thinklinux I meant the OP, not you. We posted our comments roughly at the same time (probably with the same intention ;) ).

Comment: @Carsten Oh.. then I'm sorry!

Comment: @Carsten Abandon in the sense of using pure JS instead of JS and PHP.

Comment: @acid I strongly advice you to read a lot! Read about meteor and about nodejs and understand the concepts. You can start from the meteor docs http://docs.meteor.com/.

Answer (score 15):

As many people have mentioned, server-side JS would replace the function of PHP completely. But Meteor is much more than that; it allows you to replace your imperative code with declarative code. Meteor takes care of synchronizing the data and you just decide how to render it. No more passing around messages through AJAX. As one article put it, [Meteor has made MVC obsolete](http://newcome.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/the-future-of-web-development-isnt-mvc-its-mvm/).

In my experience with meteor, I'm developing a project and [reading the book](http://www.discovermeteor.com/). What I've been able to do with Meteor in a short time has completely blown my mind. Combined with some excellent frontend frameworks such as bootstrap, I don't really have to do any CSS work either (if I don't want to), and that means I can develop without worrying about styling or AJAX, essentially freeing up my time to create awesome applications with very little legwork.

Besides, as they say, it only takes a weekend to try Meteor out. It's not complicated at all if you have JS experience. However, as it took me a bit to understand, it's not necessary to think with MVC anymore. It only took me a couple of days to build my first meteor app so I suggest you try it out!

Comment: Thanks for sharing from your personal experience. For a Java programmer without web experience, what kind of learning path she/he need to take (what are the prerequisites)? Core JS + CSS3 + HTML5 (syntax) + jquery? -- you said CSS may not be required, so I guess the above listed may not be all required.

Comment: Just knowing JavaScript really. HTML is simple..

Comment: Are you still liking meteor in Q1 of 2014?

Comment: Heck yes! Meteor has prompted me to develop tons of interesting things on GitHub: https://github.com/mizzao. Don't wait, just get your hands dirty - there's no going back.